# why is the *set_capture* of an element affected by the *set_capture* of its parent?

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml

why is it that this code:

html:

```
<div id="outer" >
    Outer Div
    <div id="inner" >
        Inner Div
    </div>
</div>
```

onload:

```
document.getElementById("outer").addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    alert('outer');
}, true);

document.getElementById("inner").addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
    alert('inner');
}, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fGZ3U/

gives us an alert `outer` followed by an alert `inner`?

In the *use_capture* argument for inner, it is set to false, which means that the events should start from 'inner', shouldn't it?

I understand that if we set the outer's *set_capture* to false, then the result would be `inner` followed by `outer`, but i do not see how the *set_capture* value for outer should have any effect on the result here.

Answer (score 0):

no it shouldn't - use_capture argument sets in which part of event processing is this event triggered

1. part is capture ( use_capture = true )
   it is starting from window to the deepest element in tree
2. part is bubbling
   it is starting ftom deepest element and goes to the window

( in your case outer is first due to it is triggered in first part )

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html